# Rails and DynamoDB: Do I need initialize Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, amazon-dynamodb

When I create a new Ruby on Rails app which will be working with DynamoDB, should I create project with Active Record or without?

Should I use command:

A)

```
$ rails new app_name
```

or B)

```
$ rails new appname --skip-active-record
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, DynamoDB is not compatible with ActiveRecord (being a NoSQL database and all). So yeah, skip AR.